# Finding most occuring sequence in a dataframe column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

I have a dataframe which looks as follows

```
id  locationID
1   2345
1   5678
1   9568
1   1234
1   9876
1   2345
1   5678
1   9568
2   1234
2   9876
2   2345
2   5678
```

From this, I am trying to find out the most commonly repeating sequence and the result should look as follows:

```
sequence                         count
9876,2345,5678                    2
2345,5678,9568                    2 
2345,5678                         3

so on and so forth
```

solutions tried:

1. for a two item list, I pasted the the `locationID` and
   `lead(locationID)` and could find the most common sequence
2. 

```
df1 <- df %>%    
       arrange(id) %>%    
       group_by(id) %>%    
       summarise(new = paste(unique(combn(locationID,
       length(unique(locationID)), toString)), collapse = '/'))
```

however, received an error with the above sequncing effort which is as follows:
`x invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)`

Comment: Does the number of elements of the sequences have an upper bound?

Comment: 10 is a reasonable upper bound according to the case in question.